# Exporting class containing an ObservableCollection to csv in C#

Tags: csv, export

I've found many solutions for exporting a class to CSV but my problem is this:

The class I'm trying to export has a property that is an observablecollection. eg:

```
public class ShipmentForExport
    {
        public string WaybillNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime WaybillDate { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
        public string CollectingBranchName { get; set; }
        public string CollectingBranchCode { get; set; }
        public string RecipientName { get; set; }
        public string RecipientPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string RecipientCellphoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string RecipientCompany { get; set; }
        public string DestinationAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string DestinationAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string DestinationCity { get; set; }
        public string DestinationSuburb { get; set; }
        public string DestinationProvince { get; set; }
        public string DestinationCountry { get; set; }
        public string DestinationPostalCode { get; set; }

        ***public ObservableCollection<InHouseParcel> Parcels { get; set; }***

    }
```

When I try export a list of shipments to csv it works but obviously the parcels do not export the way I want them to.

I have tried using Filehelpers Library and csvHelper as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Using [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain)...

When writing, you'll have to write manually because writing of collection properties isn't supported.

```
foreach( var record in records )
{
    csv.WriteField( record.WaybillNumber );
    ...
    foreach( var parcel in record.Parcels )
    {
        csv.WriteField( parcel );
    }
}
```

Reading is a little easier because you can add it in the mapping.

```
Map( m => m.Parcels ).ConvertUsing( row =>
{
    var oc = new ObservableCollection<InHouseParcel>();
    var parcel = row.GetField<InHouseParcel>( 17 );
    oc.Add( parcel );
} );
```

You'll need to convert the field values into `InHouseParcel` and loop through the remainder of the fields in the row. I'll leave that task to you.

Answer (score 0):

Josh's answer is outdated nowadays. You can use a typeconverter like:

```
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterFactory.AddConverter<ObservableCollection<string>>(new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.StringListConverter());

using (var txt = new StreamReader(filename))
using (var reader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(txt))
{ .... }



namespace CsvHelper.TypeConversion
{
public sealed class StringListConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
    {
        var oc = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        if (text.IndexOf('|') >= 0)
        {
            var list = text.Split('|').ToList<string>();// base.ConvertFromString(options, text);
            oc = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);
        }
        return oc;
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(TypeConverterOptions options, object value)
    {
        var l = value as IEnumerable<string>;
        if ( l == null || l.Count() == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }

        return string.Join("|", l);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

}